# writing wrong labels on point using fact_wrap() with geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-text, facet-grid

I want to write the percentage on each point.

Data :[sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRocS.png)

plot code :-

```
plot2 <- ggplot(counter2,aes(x= as.character(week) ,y =freq,group=Delivery.time))+
  geom_point(colour = "red")+
  geom_line(colour = "red")+
  labs(x="Month",y="Number Of Customers")+
  facet_grid(.~Delivery.time)+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
  geom_text(aes(label = freq),size = 2.5, hjust = .5, vjust=-0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~Delivery.time, ncol = 1)
plot2 +geom_text(aes(label = paste("(",as.character(counter2$ratio),"%)",sep = "") ),size = 2.25, hjust = .5, vjust=-3)+
  ylim(0,70)
```

output:- [image: output graph for first weeks in the data]

it displays the percentage on wrong points, It parse all points horizontal and put the first percentage on the first point of the top graph then the second percentage in the dataframe on the second point of the top graph it should be on the first point on the second graph

Comment: Please include a portion of the data, not a picture of the data. Use `dput`

Comment: Problem is probably the `$`

Comment: I removed the $ and it works well, Thank you